# Android-Bottom sheet does not expand

Tags: android, android-support-library, drawerlayout, bottom-sheet

So basically,i'm using the bottom sheet view from the support library. It opens up after a FAB is pressed.

This is the bottom sheet view file:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/bottomSheetView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"

>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="New"
    android:id="@+id/newLabel"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newLabel"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newFileButton"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="File"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newFolderButton"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Folder"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the main activity layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
>



<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

>

<!-- The first child in the layout is for the main Activity UI-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/cwdLabel" />

    <!--view that creates a dividing line between listview and textview -->  
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cwdLabel"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fileList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cwdLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_18dp"
        />




</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"
    />




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


<include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_new"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is, that the bottom sheet doesn't open when you press the FAB.
Instead, it opens after you slide the drawer out.Also, the bottom sheet is transparent, which is not what i have set it to be.

I searched around for answers, and after reading a few other questions, i think it has to do with the elevation of the drawer layout, but i don't really know how to solve that problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I updated the com.android.support:appcompat to the last version and now it works!

Nowadays I have

- 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
- 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

Answer (score 0):

Try this, 
Put this after initilizing views

```
  ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(coordinator, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(coordinator);
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps